# Placing key/value pairs from dict into .set() values in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter

In Tkinter, I'm trying to place key/value pairs from a dictionary called 'headers' inside the set() pairs in the set_values tuple below.

Before this process I open a json file, deserialize the data into a dictionary called `headers`. This dictionary is for API headers in the Tkinter App.

The `set_value` pairs are 5 pairs of entries for API header keys and values. So, if the dict headers only ends up being 3 key/value pairs, I don't want to use all 5 set_value's, I'd only want to use 3.

Basically I'm thinking of a way to place the headers key/value pairs inside the .set() respected number of .set() pairs.  *See bottom for expected output.*

I have a dict() named headers:

```
headers = {'First': variable1, 'Second': variable2, 'Third': variable3}
```

And, on Tkinter, I have about 5 different pairs of `Entries` (below):  I put these `.sets()` inside a tuple because I'm thinking it may be easier to iterate & set key/value pairs from headers into set_values below. Or a dict may work better.

```
set_values = ( ( 1_key_entry.set(),  1_value_entry.set() ),
               ( 2_key_entry.set(), 2_value_entry.set() ),
               ( 3_key_entry.set(), 3_value_entry.set() ),
               ( 4_key_entry.set(), 4_value_entry.set() ),
               ( 5_key_entry.set(), 5_value_entry.set() ),
              )
```

Now, based on the length of `headers`, say 3, I only want those 3 key/value pairs from headers to be inserted inside the .set()'s in `set_values`.

**My desired output would be: (Notice the `.set(key)` and `.set(value)`):**

```
set_values = ( ( 1_key_entry.set('First'), 1_value_entry.set(variable1) ),
               ( 2_key_entry.set('Second'), 2_value_entry.set(variable2) ),
               ( 3_key_entry.set('Third'), 3_value_entry.set(variable3) )
             )
```

Lengths:

```
x = len(headers)   # Length of dict headers

y = set_values[:x]  # set_values pairs needed based on length of headers.
```

In my App, I have an easy work around but it is based off asserting k is equal to a user input like Content-Type, Authorization etc in the entry field.

```
for k, v in json_file.items():
    if k == 'Content-Type':
        1_key_entry.set(k)
        1_value_entry.set(v)
    elif k == 'Authorization':
        2_key_entry.set(k)
        2_value_entry.set(v)
       .
       .
       .
```

However, what I need is that any k/v pair in the headers dictionary can be automatically set to a set() pair in set_values.

Comment: You really want your Entries to be contained in lists, rather than having individual variable names.  That way, you can simply write a loop that iterates over your dict items and sets the corresponding Entries.

Comment: Hey @jasonharper, so are you saying have the actual tk.Entry() 's in lists instead of given them variables names? Any chance have an example of that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're after, but if I understand correctly: you want to split up key/value pairs from a JSON dictionary into pairs of tkinter `Entry` widgets?

If that's the case, then here is an example of how to do that in a loop:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
# get your values however you need to, I'm just using numbers as placeholders
headers = {
    'First': 1,
    'Second': 2,
    'Third': 3,
}

# notice how Entry is only being instantiated twice in this loop...
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(headers.items()):
    # column of Entry widgets w/ text from dict keys
    ent_k = tk.Entry(root)
    ent_k.insert(tk.END, k)
    ent_k.grid(i, 0)
    # column of Entry widgets w/ text from dict values
    ent_v = tk.Entry(root)
    ent_v.insert(tk.END, v)
    ent_v.grid(i, 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Does that help?

Note that the tricky part of declaring widgets in a loop like this is that accessing the individual entries can't be done by name, so setting their values programmatically becomes difficult. You may have to resort to some kind of trickery involving `root.winfo_children()` to get a list of the widgets in the parent window...

Comment: Are you suggesting that each `ent_k` and `ent_v` assignment creates a new variable based on the current value of `k` and `v`? If so, you need to use a *dict*, so that you can write something like `d[f'ent_{k}'] = tk.Entry(root)`.

Comment: @chepner That's a clever solution! I like it.

Comment: Any time. Happy to help!